# How to convert GMT date time into GMT Unix TimeStamp using JS?

Tags: javascript, datetime, unix-timestamp, gmt

I know there are various ways using which we can convert date time into Unix timestamp.

But the problem is when we convert GMT's Date time value into Unix timestamp then it shows the value of timestamp according to my local timezone's value i.e. Asia/Kolkata

For example:
Date time of GMT is: 2018-08-21 11:37:56 So when I am converting it into Unix timestamp then it returns as follows:

```
var t = new Date('2018-08-21 11:37:56').getTime() / 1000;
console.log(t); // 1534831676
```

I am looking for `1534851476` which is a value according to the GMT time zone.

which is Unix timestamp according to my local time zone Asia/Kolkata. Can anyone help me out to get Unix timestamp value into GMT?

For more information: you can check the Unix timestamp value of GMT date time here [on this link](https://www.epochconverter.com/).

Thank you!

Comment: try `new Date('2018-08-21T11:37:56Z').getTime() / 1000`

Comment: If you don't include time zone information in the date string, how can you expect it to know that you want UTC time?

Comment: on that point, some variants of input to Date constructor **do** assume UTC :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I am having value of date time as 2018-08-21 11:37:56 in the database.

Comment: well that's simple to change  ... `'2018-08-21 11:37:56'.replace(' ', 'T')+'Z'`

Comment: @JaromandaX well sure, the numeric UTC setters, but in this case it's a string. And storing string dates in a database is pretty weird.

Comment: May not be storing them that way, just the retrieval gets them that way

Comment: I know but it is provided... and changes are costly @Pointy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a timezone, new Date assumes localtime

so, lets say you retrieve the string

```
var date = '2018-08-21 11:37:56';
```

what you can do is

```js
var date = '2018-08-21 11:37:56';
var t = new Date(date.replace(' ', 'T') + 'Z').getTime() / 1000;
console.log(t); // 1534851476 - see for yourself
```